# Pattern for collecting data from multiple sources

Tags: java, design-patterns, clean-architecture

I writing a java service that collect cryptocurrency data and I am wondering what desing pattern would be the best for that. There are some free APIs (lets call it data providers) for that on the web.

Basicly I will have some entities in my database like for example bitcoin, ethereum, dogecoin, and I need to find the current data about price, trading volume etc for each of them in the data returned from data provider.

First of all I would like to have control over the time interval in which the data are collected. Secondly I want to have few data providers registered in my service, in case that one on them stop working or api change. The returned data schema is different for each data provider, so I think that each data provider will need its own mapper (or is there another way for solving this problem?). I am also wondering what is the easiest way to maintain such service as the providers API might change or some new providers show up, and I would like to have possibility to easily add new provider or delete the old one.

Do you see any patterns that fits the best that requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Next combination of patterns can solve your problem:

- *Abstract Factory* - allows the creation of objects without specifying their concrete type.
- *Facade* - provides a simple interface to a more complex underlying object.
- *Adapter* - allows for two incompatible classes to work together by wrapping an interface around one of the existing classes.
- *Assembler* -  transfer data between the DTO and any domain objects